Find out the 6 locker numbers
Louis, a 57-year-old man, found a note after waking up one morning from his wife, who had gone missing.
The note said:

I have added 6 pieces of paper in 6 different lockers from 10 ~ 99. Remove all of the numbers that I dislike, and you get the message. If you open an empty locker, the whole locker system will lock forever.

He knew that the numbers that his wife disliked were the numbers that are a multiple of 13, and the ones where if you change one of the digits of a number, is divisible by 13.
To solve the problem, you need to:

Find the 6 locker numbers that the pieces of paper are in.

Hint 1

 What happens if you change the units digit?

Hint 2

 What happens if you change the tens digit?


Answer:

 Check lockers $40$, $44$, $47$, $80$, $84$, $87$.

Solution:

 The two-digit multiples of $13$ are $13$, $26$, $39$, $52$, $65$, $78$, and $91$. A number is "bad" if and only if it shares one or more digits with the multiples of 13. This means that "good" numbers must start with either $4$ or $8$, and end in either $4$, $7$, or $0$.

